# For any integer $n>1$, there always exists at least one prime number $p$ with $n < p< n+\left(\ln\Big(\frac{n}{\ln n}\Big)+1\right)^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

**Question:** Is the conjecture as follows true or false?

> > For any integer $n>1$, there always exists at least one prime number $p$ with
> >
> > $$n < p< n+\left(\ln\Big(\frac{n}{\ln n}\Big)+1\right)^2$$

The conjecture was checked true with $n$ up to $10^8$ and some [The 80 known maximal prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results)

Comment: You may want to read this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap It discusses both the known upper and lower bounds and the conjectures which LAGRIDA talks about in their answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

False.

Let $n=1693182318746371$. The next prime after $n$ is $1693182318747503$.

$(\ln(\frac{n}{\ln n})+1)^2 \le1057$, but the prime gap is $1132$.

Comment: How did you construct this huge example? Is there some list of the largest prime gaps?

Comment: Don't know if this is how it was found, but the number appears in the tables of this page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

Answer (score 7):

Your conjecture is not compatible with some actual heuristic views:

**Cramer Conjecture:**
$$\limsup_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\log(p_n)^2}=1$$

Then if this conjecture holds, we have infinitly many intervals of size $(1+o(1))\log(n)^2$ does not contain any prime numbers.

**Granvile conjecture:**
$$\limsup_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\log(p_n)^2}\gtrsim2e^{-\gamma}\approx1.12$$
*($f(x) \gtrsim g(x) \iff f(x) \geq (1+o(1))g(x)$)*

Then if Granvile's conjecture holds, we have infinitly many intervals of size $(2e^{-\gamma}+o(1))\log(n)^2$ does not contain any prime numbers.

You can see that $2e^{-\gamma} > 1$, then **Granvile's conjecture holds** implies that your conjecture is false.

Comment: I think Granville conjectured that this limsup is $\ge 2e^{-\gamma}$, not necessarily $=2e^{-\gamma}$.